# Getting properties from generic type used in abstract superclass without using interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

Is there any nice, elegant way to get properties from generic type used in abstract superclass without using interfaces?
Here's an example:

```
 public abstract class CoolBase<T>
    where T : class
{
    private IEnumerable<T> somEnumerable; 
    public void GetPersonProperties()
    {
       var name = somEnumerable.First().Name; //this doesn't work
    }

}

public class CoolA : CoolBase<Person>
{

}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to get `Person` details inside `CoolBase`, then `CoolBase` cannot be generic, it needs to know about `Person`. If you want `CoolBase` to be generic, then you do not want code specific to `Person` inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to put `GetPersonProperties` in `CoolBase`. `CoolBase` is generic, so should not have a class-specific functionality within it.

You could create a abstract method in `CoolBase` and implement it in your derived type:

```
public abstract class CoolBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected IEnumerable<T> somEnumerable;

    public abstract void GetProperties();
}

public class CoolA : CoolBase<Person>
{
    public override void GetProperties()
    {
        var name = somEnumerable.First().Name;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could you reflection to get at the properties of `T` at runtime:

```
public abstract class CoolBase<T> where T : class
{
    private IEnumerable<T> somEnumerable;

    public void GetProperties()
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof (T).GetProperties())
        {
            // do something with each property
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal of using generic classes is type-flexibility - 
therefore it makes no sence to declare a method in a generic class which 
uses Person-specific methods.

You should implement such detailed methods in the concrete implementations of 
your abstract, generic class (here `CoolA`).

Maybe it is helpful for you to declare an abstract method getProperties() 
int the generic, abstract class, wich can be implemented in CoolA via using 
Person-specific code.

```
public abstract class CoolBase<T>
    where T : class
{
    private IEnumerable<T> somEnumerable; 

    public abstract void getProperties();    
}

public class CoolA : CoolBase<Person>
{    
    public override void getProperties()
    {
       //should work, somEnumberable is made of Persons here
       var name = somEnumerable.First().Name;
    }
}
```